# Relative word match in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

New to the Elastic search, Below is what i am trying to achieve where anything that relatively matches with an query string should return the result

Creating sample Indexes like below

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/prj1/mod/java' -d '{
    "project_name": "Java_SE"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/prj1/mod/java2Ed' -d '{
    "project_name": "Java 2 Edition"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/prj1/mod/javaee' -d '{
    "project_name": "Java_EE"
}'
```

When searching

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/prj1/mod/_search' -d '{"query" : {"match" : {"project_name" : "Java"}}}'
```

Returns below results

```
{"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.15342641,"hits":[{"_index":"prj1","_type":"mod","_id":"java2Ed","_score":0.15342641,"_source":{
"project_name": "Java 2 Edition"
}}]}}
```

It does not return all the Projects with the name like "Java_SE", "Java 2 Edition" and "Java_EE".

need to get everything where it finds with match text "example" 
I could be have data like this in my text as well

This is an example_code
This example:11 is good
Example you are looking for is not available.

What is that i m doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [edge ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) filter for this problem. Create your index with following setup

```
PUT prj1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "ngram_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 8
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "relative": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "ngram_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mod": {
      "properties": {
        "project_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "relative",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so *java_se* will have tokens *ja*, *jav* *java* etc and your `match query` will work.

Thanks to @sean, You would need to use [ngram filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) for words like *complete_java_book*, *my_java_applet* etc. You might want to consider breaking words on `_` if you are using `_` as naming convention for project names, are you?

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution is not necessarily correct, although it will work in the example given in the question, it will not in many similar or likely examples. For example, a title "the_complete_java_book" will not match against a search "java" using the mapping you have given. In fact, any title that does not begin "java" there would be no match.

Comment: @sean, yes you are right, you would have to use `ngram` for that. Also much better would be to break words on underscore assuming all the projects are using underscore as naming convention. I ll update the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, it all depends on what you can assume about the contents of the title field and the desired matching behavior which isn't clear from the question :)

Comment: @ ChintanShah25 , Can't we use queryString and pass regex like  java*.Since project name is analysed, query string should work on it.

Comment: @Richa yes it will work but wont match `complete_java_book` as sean pointed out. you would have to use `*java*` which is not recommended as it will scan every token in inverted index. OP has not specified any particular pattern which would help us give better solution

Comment: @ ChintanShah25 ,Thanks for the explanation.But What does OP refer to here?

Comment: @Richa it means original poster(person who asked the question), also I just realized now `java*` will do what edge ngram will but it will be a bit faster. Thanks for that.

Comment: will add that in answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, by default, elasticsearch will use the [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/standard-tokenizer.html) which will not split text on the underscore "_" character. Therefore when you perform your search, you are searching for the "java" token which only the document java2ED has a token for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query_string` as well.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/prj1/mod/_search' -d '{"query" : {"query_string" : {"project_name" : "*Java*"}}}'
```